# iterate rows and combine them if they don't start with a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

May I get some help on how to combine lines 1-7 so that they appear on a single line inside a csv file?  I tried to put this into a dataframe but the formatting messes up the data in the first column.

```
1527047244357,'line_A','{}','{
<gpx abcd>
    <rte>
        <name>defg</name>
    </rte>
</gpx>
}'
1527047244358,'line_B'
```

There are thousands of lines in each csv files that I'm working with and these lines happen randomly within the file.  I'm thinking that maybe a for loop would work to check if the first char is a number and if not, delete the line break so that I can get what I needed:

```
1527047244357,'line_A','{}','{<gpx abcd><rte><name>defg</name></rte></gpx>}'
1527047244358,'line_B'
```

How can I accomplish this?  Here's my pseudo code so far:

```
for row in readerObj:
    if isinstance(row[0], int) == True:
         (delete line break)
    csvWriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
s = """1527047244357,'line_A','{}','{
<gpx abcd>
    <rte>
        <name>defg</name>
    </rte>
</gpx>
}'
1527047244358,'line_B'"""

res = [[]]
checkVal = False
for line in s.splitlines():             #Iterate Each line
    if line.strip().endswith("{"):      #Check if line ends with {
        checkVal = True
    if line.strip().endswith("}'"):     #Check if line ends with }
        checkVal = False
        res[-1].append(line)
        continue

    if checkVal:
        res[-1].append(line)
    else:
        res.append([line])

for i in res:
    print(" ".join(i))
```

**Output:**

```
1527047244357,'line_A','{}','{ <gpx abcd>     <rte>         <name>defg</name>     </rte> </gpx> }'
1527047244358,'line_B'
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh!  Since iterating over csv.reader changed each row to a list I had to tweak some code using yours as reference.

    for row in readerObj:
        if "}'" not in row[-1]:
            temp_row.extend(row)
            continue
        elif "}'" in row[-1]:
            if temp_row != []:
                temp_row.extend(row)
                temp_row[5] = ''.join(temp_row[5:])
                csvWriter.writerow(temp_row)
                temp_row.clear()
                continue
            csvWriter.writerow(row)

Answer (score 1):

Most csv data uses `"` as the quote character.  Yours uses `'` instead, which can be controlled with the [`quotechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) parameter, supported by both `csv.reader` and `pd.read_csv`:

```
In [61]: pd.read_csv("data.csv", quotechar="'", header=None)
Out[61]: 
               0       1    2                                                  3
0  1527047244357  line_A   {}  {\r\n<gpx abcd>\r\n    <rte>\r\n        <name>...
1  1527047244358  line_B  NaN                                                NaN
```

Once you've got this, you can strip as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on quotechar.  I have added it via:

df = pd.read_csv(output_file, header = None, quotechar = "'")

However, when I use astype('int64') on the first column the code still run in to an error.  I'll dig deeper on this but I don't think my code with quotechar is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Read the original file one line at a time and write the lines to the output file without line breaks, *unless* a line starts with a number (in which case it is the next row and a line break must be inserted before it):

```
import re
with open("original.csv") as infile:
    with open("fixed.csv", "w") as outfile:
        for lineno,line in enumerate(infile):
            # The beginning of the next row
            if re.match('\d+,', line) and lineno > 0: 
                outfile.write('\n')
            outfile.write(line.rstrip())
```

The variable `lineno` prevents the code from inserting a line break at the beginning of the file. Using this method, you can process arbitrary long files because you always deal with at most one row.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it similar to your code and easy to understand.

```
readerObj = """1527047244357,'line_A','{}','{
<gpx abcd>
    <rte>
        <name>defg</name>
    </rte>
</gpx>
}'
1527047244358,'line_B'"""

temp_csv = ''

for line in readerObj.splitlines():
    line_splitted = line.split(',')
    dumped_whitespaces = [el.strip(' ') for el in line_splitted]
    first_obj = line_splitted[0]

    # that's the recommended way to check if something is a digit
    if first_obj.isdigit():
        # adds new line
        temp_csv += "\n"

    temp_csv += ','.join(dumped_whitespaces)

with open('yourfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(temp_csv)
```

Results with

```
1527047244357,'line_A','{}','{<gpx abcd><rte><name>defg</name></rte></gpx>}'
1527047244358,'line_B'
```

If you need to make sure everything looks fine use pandas.